# Anyways to automate finding Unused JavaScript And CSS?

Tags: automation, google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage

Right now, we can find Unused JavaScript And CSS With The Coverage Tab using the Chrome Dev tool, is there any way to integrate this into the Selenium test?
Any suggestion?
Thank you